# Display Numbers to words in textbox or lable in asp.net,C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
```

And my code behind code is:

```
 public String changeToWords(String numb)
{
    String val = "", wholeNo = numb, points = "", andStr = "", pointStr = "";
    String endStr = ("");
    try
    {
        int decimalPlace = numb.IndexOf(".");
        if (decimalPlace > 0)
        {
            wholeNo = numb.Substring(0, decimalPlace);
            points = numb.Substring(decimalPlace + 1);
            if (Convert.ToInt32(points) > 0)
            {
                andStr = ("point");// just to separate whole numbers from points/Rupees

            }
        }
        val = String.Format("{0} {1}{2} {3}", translateWholeNumber(wholeNo).Trim(), andStr, pointStr, endStr);
    }
    catch
    {
        ;
    }
    return val;
}

private String translateWholeNumber(String number)
{
    string word = "";
    try
    {
        bool beginsZero = false;//tests for 0XX
        bool isDone = false;//test if already translated
        double dblAmt = (Convert.ToDouble(number));
        //if ((dblAmt > 0) && number.StartsWith("0"))

        if (dblAmt > 0)
        {//test for zero or digit zero in a nuemric
            beginsZero = number.StartsWith("0");
            int numDigits = number.Length;
            int pos = 0;//store digit grouping
            String place = "";//digit grouping name:hundres,thousand,etc...
            switch (numDigits)
            {
                case 1://ones' range
                    word = ones(number);
                    isDone = true;
                    break;
                case 2://tens' range
                    word = tens(number);
                    isDone = true;
                    break;
                case 3://hundreds' range
                    pos = (numDigits % 3) + 1;
                    place = " Hundred ";
                    break;
                case 4://thousands' range
                case 5:
                case 6:
                    pos = (numDigits % 4) + 1;
                    place = " Thousand ";
                    break;
                case 7://millions' range
                case 8:
                case 9:
                    pos = (numDigits % 7) + 1;
                    place = " Million ";
                    break;
                case 10://Billions's range
                    pos = (numDigits % 10) + 1;
                    place = " Billion ";
                    break;
                //add extra case options for anything above Billion...
                default:
                    isDone = true;
                    break;
            }
            if (!isDone)
            {//if transalation is not done, continue...(Recursion comes in now!!)
                word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos));
                //check for trailing zeros
                if (beginsZero) word = " and " + word.Trim();
            }
            //ignore digit grouping names
            if (word.Trim().Equals(place.Trim())) word = "";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        ;
    }
    return word.Trim();
}

private String tens(String digit)
{
    int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
    String name = null;
    switch (digt)
    {
        case 10:
            name = "Ten";
            break;
        case 11:
            name = "Eleven";
            break;
        case 12:
            name = "Twelve";
            break;
        case 13:
            name = "Thirteen";
            break;
        case 14:
            name = "Fourteen";
            break;
        case 15:
            name = "Fifteen";
            break;
        case 16:
            name = "Sixteen";
            break;
        case 17:
            name = "Seventeen";
            break;
        case 18:
            name = "Eighteen";
            break;
        case 19:
            name = "Nineteen";
            break;
        case 20:
            name = "Twenty";
            break;
        case 30:
            name = "Thirty";
            break;
        case 40:
            name = "Fourty";
            break;
        case 50:
            name = "Fifty";
            break;
        case 60:
            name = "Sixty";
            break;
        case 70:
            name = "Seventy";
            break;
        case 80:
            name = "Eighty";
            break;
        case 90:
            name = "Ninety";
            break;
        default:
            if (digt > 0)
            {
                name = tens(digit.Substring(0, 1) + "0") + " " + ones(digit.Substring(1));
            }
            break;
    }
    return name;
}

private String ones(String digit)
{
    int digt = Convert.ToInt32(digit);
    String name = "";
    switch (digt)
    {
        case 1:
            name = "One";
            break;
        case 2:
            name = "Two";
            break;
        case 3:
            name = "Three";
            break;
        case 4:
            name = "Four";
            break;
        case 5:
            name = "Five";
            break;
        case 6:
            name = "Six";
            break;
        case 7:
            name = "Seven";
            break;
        case 8:
            name = "Eight";
            break;
        case 9:
            name = "Nine";
            break;
    }
    return name;
}
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox2.Text = changeToWords(TextBox1.Text);
}
```

it is working properly but what i want is when i am typeing in textbox it automatically shows in another textbox and I want to show numbers to words in lakhs also.... please help me

Comment: For that you have to be use javascript.

Comment: If u dnt mind will u give some example code please.....

Comment: i have given the link below check. You can also check this link. http://jsfiddle.net/j5kdG/